# Bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I was trying to collapse the paragraph below when I click on the button "Lorem ipsum 1" but when I did it doesn't collapse. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h1><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1Content">Lorem ipsum 1</button></h1>
            <div id="col1Content" class="collapse in">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>   
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think might be probably because you are linking to jquery 3.1.0 and bootstrap 3 js is supposed to be used with jquery above 1.9 and below jquery 3 try linking to a different jquery and try it like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code locally and also it doesn't work, although the code you have is correct.

Try to download the bootstrap and include it in your project including the jquery library,

like for example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
<script src="_assets/js/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="_assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and it will work.